# How to create a soap service in mule4?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, anypoint-studio

Can anyone please help on creating a soap service in mule4?
I have referred the documentation but no luck.

Thanks,
Vempati

Answer (score 0):

In Mule 4 use APIKit for SOAP.

For a new project: Create a new Mule project and in *API Implementation*, 
check *Specify API Definition File Location or URL*, and browse to the WSDL. Follow the instructions and it will generate skeleton flows for all your SOAP services and operations.

For an existing project: add the wsdl to `src/main/resources` somewhere. Right click, choose *mule*->*Generate Flows from WSDL* and follow the prompts.

More detailed information you will need depends on your use-case and wsdl which can be found in the documentation here: 
https://docs.mulesoft.com/apikit/4.x/apikit-4-for-soap

Comment: Thanks for the input, I have tried the same process of generating flows. just to add to your steps: We should refresh the project to get the wsdl in src/main/resource/api folder. Now I am facing the below Issue in generating the flows from wsdl. Can you please assist?  Log:Problem parsing config file: C:/mule/mvrsoap.xml
  An error occurred while deserializing the ArtifactDeclaration
.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.mule.connectors:mule-http-connector:jar:mule-plugin:1.3.2 from/to maven.oracle.com (https://maven.oracle.com): Authorization Required (401)

Comment: You need to add mulesoft Maven repositories to your pom.